# ¿Por qué no puedo crear tablas en pycharm con CREATE TABLE?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Usando pycharm quiero crear una tabla en una base de datos con "CREATE TABLE tabla(......)" pero no reconoce las palabras como alguna instrucción, ya cree el archivo .db pero dentro de él solo hay texto, des decir, como si todo lo que estuviera en comillas fuera un comentario, muestro código en pycharm (ya importé el módulo de sqlite3, y creé el "cursor"):

```
c.execute(""" CREATE TABLE nombres (
        nombre text,
        apellido text,
        dirección text,
        ciudad text,
        zipcode integer
    )""")
```

Este código no funciona en pycharm pero en sublime text sí, o sea, en subtext sí aparecen las palabras como instrucciones. Pido asesoría, gracias.
Aquí muestro la diferencia:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen anterior es en sublime text.
La que sigue es en pycharm:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, debes indicar cuál era el resultado que esperabas. No veo ningún error en lo que comentas.

Comment: Muy bien, un un momento muestro a lo que me refiero, una disculpa.

Comment: Edito pregunta.

Comment: Eso no es ninguna incidencia, es solo que el sistema de resaltado de código de PyCharm no detecta que eso es una consulta SQL y lo trata como una cadena de texto de Python sin más. Eso no afecta en nada a la funcionalidad del código, al intérprete le da exactamente igual eso, es solo un tema visual que ayuda al programador, nada más. La tabla se creará igualmente, ni Pycharm ni Sublime ejecutan nada, son meros editores de texto con algunas ayudas, como el resaltado, autocompletado, etc, eso es cosa del intérprete Python.

Comment: La cosa es que revisando el contenido del archivo al cual agregué esa tabla, no existe ninguna tabla sino lo que está entre comillas, literalmente está escrito, no sé por qué no se creó ninguna tabla.

Comment: ¿te refieres a que abres address_book.db? La tabla se crea, no esperes una estructura tabular en el archivo... el archivo es la forma que tiene SQLITE de almacenar la base de datos y no es algo que esté pensado para que lo lean humanos... Si te interesa aquí tienes un enlace a la DOC oficial que explica su estructura: https://sqlite.org/fileformat.html

Comment: SQLite format 3      @              .?�
  < <�A     �Ytablenombresnombres CREATE TABLE nombres (
nombre text,
apellido text,
dirección text,
ciudad text,
zipcode integer
)
  
Así sale el código... ¿significa que funcionó? y por cierto, gracias por el enlace.

Comment: Si, es un archivo binario en realidad (por eso los caracteres extraños) y destinado a almacenar los datos y a ser leído y escrito por el motor de la BD no por el usuario, si tu BD tiene una sola tabla sin datos agregados la estructura recuerda mucho a la sintaxis de la consulta, pero no es igual (todo es más complejo como puedes ver en la documentación), es la forma en la que almacena internamente la estructura de la tabla.

Comment: Si quieres ver el resultado debes abrir el archivo con un browser de bases de datos. [Aquí hay uno](https://sqlitebrowser.org/), además recuerda que si ya ejecutaste el código se va a modificar el archivo, cuando lo vuelvas a ejectar te va a dar error por que esos cambios ya los hiciste. Saludos

Comment: Entendido, se los agradezco mucho. Saludos.